# Is it possible to programmatically input values in TextBox control before UpdateCommand runs

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, textbox

(C# asp.net 3.5) I have successfully pre-populated `CheckBoxList3` in `RowDataBound` event.  In edit mode, user may then make other `checkbox` selections.  I have successfully captured the new values, creating a new comma-delimited string that updates SQL in `_RowUpdating` event after Update link is clicked.  The problem is my update is being overriden by the GridView1s update. **The new string is not physically input by user in the TextBox2 control.*

It seems I have two choices:

1. Pass the comma-delimited string built from checkboxlist3 selections
   to TextBox2 control programmatically before UpdateCommand is run. P**Is this possible?**  I've
   googled everywhere with no clearcut solutions. I've also tried this code in RowUpdating and it makes to difference:

   `TextBox tb2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox2");
    tb2.Text = strCheckBoxList3.Substring(0, strCheckBoxList3.Length - 2);`
2. Update sql manually like I'm doing only place Sql call AFTER the "natural" update (for lack of
   better words). If this is an option, **what method to run the update in** because placing it in RowUpdating always gets reversed.

HTML:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Endorsements" SortExpression="Endorsements">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Endorsements") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Endorsements") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList3" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" onselectedindexchanged="CheckBoxList3_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                    AutoPostBack="True" >
                    <asp:ListItem Value="H">H</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="I">I</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="K">K</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="N">N</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="T">T</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="X">X</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

C#

```
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {             
            //endorsements string
            string strCheckBoxList3 = String.Empty;

            //find endorsements checkboxlist in gridview. 
            CheckBoxList cbl3 = (CheckBoxList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("CheckBoxList3");

            try
            {
                // Build Endorsements string
                if (cbl3 != null)
                {
                    // determine which checkboxes have been checked 
                    foreach (ListItem item in cbl3.Items)
                    {
                        // is item checked?
                        if (item.Selected == true)
                        {
                            // build string  
                            strCheckBoxList3 += (item.Value + ", ");

                        }//end of if
                    }// end of foreach

                    // Save the value in ViewState object before the PostBack
                    ViewState["vsEndorsementsString"] = strCheckBoxList3; 
                }// end of if

            }// end of endorsements try

            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ez)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ez.Message + "; " + ez.Source + "; " + ez.TargetSite);
            }
//Note: routine to update SQL was removed  here
}


// New: pass strings to sql Update Command Parameters for two checkboxlist columns in gridview
    protected void sdsMySqlDataSource_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string getViewStateEndorsementsString = ViewState["vsEndorsementsString"].ToString();
        string getViewStateRestrictionsString = ViewState["vsRestrictionsString"].ToString();

        foreach (System.Data.Common.DbParameter p in e.Command.Parameters)
        {
           if (p.ParameterName == "@Endorsements" && p.Value != null) 
           {
                //Assign @Endorsements parameter
                e.Command.Parameters["@Endorsements"].Value = getViewStateEndorsementsString.ToString();
            }//if

            if (p.ParameterName == "@Restrictions" && p.Value != null) 
            {
                //Assign @Restrictions parameter
                e.Command.Parameters["@Restrictions"].Value = getViewStateRestrictionsString.ToString();
            }//if
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Are you handling the RowUpdated event?  In the RowUpdated event, can you inspect `e.Exception`, to see if some exception was raised during the update process?

Comment: I don't think I explained my question clearly.  The second parameter that comes into your RowUpdated event ([`GridUpdatedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdatedeventargs.aspx) e) has an "Exception" property.  Is `e.Exception` null, or does it have something in it?

Comment: e.Exception is null in RowUpdated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to pass new values to Update Command Parameters in SqlDataSource _Updating event.  Relevent updated code provided above.

I removed the SQL update routine that I had in _RowUpdating event entirely - it isn't needed.  Then I saved the newly created comma-delimited string to ViewState object which I retrieve in SqlDataSource _Updating event.

Credit for me coming to this conclusion goes to leoinlios because of his post here: [changing textbox value in code behind does not post back new value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429752/changing-textbox-value-in-code-behind-does-not-post-back-new-value/20431128?noredirect=1#comment33176566_20431128)  Plus I did a lot of reading about View State and found this to be the most useful article: [TRULY Understanding ViewState](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx)